# Trembling css running text animation(margin + translate) in Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

I made some running text animation animation in CSS same way, as it is in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61716504/6298055). I tried to implement it like that to avoid any JS manipulation. And everything works fine in Chrome, but text is trembling in Safari.

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(161, 61, 175);
  color: #fff;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%; /* this is to prevent shorter text animate to right */
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  animation: marquee 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  90% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="marquee">
  <span>The only thing that matters now is everything You think of me</span>
</h1>

<p class="marquee">
  <span>Beware of short texts!</span>
</p>
```

I was trying to fix that using only by using CSS, but I still cannot find the solution. Yeah, I can use JS and avoid giving animation to smaller elements. But maybe there is a way to fix this stuff for Safari with CSS only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague rewritten animation in that way, that it can be handled by Safari. It was obvious to us, that this trembling is caused by using translate + margin, that's why I mentioned it even in title. As you probably know, it is better to avoid margin animations. So, we added wrapper, which have opposite direction animation. Yeah, now we have 2 animations, but they are handled by browsers better, than one with both translation and margin

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(161, 61, 175);
  color: #fff;
}

.marquee-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  animation: marquee-wrapper 4s ease-in-out infinite;  
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%; /* this is to prevent shorter text animate to right */
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  animation: marquee 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes marquee-wrapper {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="marquee-wrapper">
    <span>
      The only thing that matters now is everything You think of me
      The only thing that matters now is everything You think of me
    </span>  
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="marquee-wrapper">
    <span>Beware of short texts!</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```